# Restore function key

Tags: python, functions, hex

I have a simple function which looks like that:

```
keyAlphabet = [-1, 16, 32, 127, 61, -32, -31, 43, 0, 88, 2, 5, 7, 112, 64, 69, 96]
key = ??? # only keyAlphabet values
p = 0x1337
for i in key:
...p*=i
...p+=0x31337
```

Finally `p` should be `0xfd0970e7`.

I've tried to subtract `0x31337` from the final result and search dividers of that value from the `keyAlphabet` (I've done that operation 8 times and after that multiple dividers came out, `0x12ef1e` can be divided with `2,7` and `61`), but because of negative values (specially `-1`) I'm not sure where should I change the sign. As a result I'm not able to find the key which will proceed values from `0x1337` into `0xfd0970e7`.

Comment: I assume original code is in assembly. Care to share that? Nuances might be lost in translation

Comment: @NirIzr here's the binary I've disassembled https://github.com/wapiflapi/exrs/blob/master/reverse/r9

Comment: @NirIzr and here's pseudo-code http://pastebin.com/3NkB3h6S. I runned this binary with chars possible to pass as argument and received this key alphabet

Comment: pseudocode shows every iteration in the last loop (the one you pasted python code for) has a different `key`. it iterates all possible values. i think that if `keyAlphabet` is actually `var_18`, you should have something like `keyAlphabet.reverse() ; for key in keyAlphabet:`

Comment: @NirIzr keyAlphabet and var_18 is just a two different variables. var_18(or key after random xoring) contains only values from keyAlphabet, but I don't know the sequence of this values. I've got this sequence in key alphabet because I've runed the program with 'qwerty...bnmQWERTY...BNM123...90_?+-' argument. Of course I've checked if value after xoring will be different if I'll swap some values in argument, but every char from input has some constant value after xor. And the alphabet I've got is the python `set()` of full alphabet

Comment: The first loop returns an array of random bytes (keyAlphabet). XOR preserves randomness so the output array is as predictable as the output of the rand generator. This means that the input only controls the length of the array of random bytes, and doesn't affect the predictability of the keyAlphabet. Selecting the correct input length such that you are more likely to get 0xfd0970e7 would seem to be the goal since the calculation in the second loop changes the randomness distribution. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3956478/understanding-randomness

Comment: Point being, I'm not sure this crackme has a deterministic solution, unless the expectation is to somehow take advantage of the implementation of "random()" in order to predict the result of keyAlphabet.

Comment: @mayahustle but each value from input turns into some value from alphabet. For example, 'q' turns into 96 and it's not necessary where is it situated, 'q' just goes into 96. So input not only sets length of the password but also sets the sequence

Comment: @mayahustle unless random() is seeded with the same seed on every execution ;)

Comment: @Nirlzr.. you're totally right. For whatever reason, that slipped my mind. http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/random.3.html says the following: "These sequences are repeatable by calling srandom() with the same seed value.  If no seed value is provided, the random() function is automatically seeded with a value of 1." Since the function is not seeding the random number generator, it's defaulting to 1, which means on every run, it should be spitting out the same sequence of characters.